# Is there any difference between Implementation dependant and undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c

Is there any difference between Implementation dependant and undefined behaviour as for C/C++ standards?

Comment: You can rely on getting the same implementation defined behaviour across multiple runs of your program on the same platform. You can't make any assumptions about undefined behaviour - two runs of the same program on the same platform could give different results.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation dependent means that a certain construct differs from platform to platform but in a defined, well-specified manner. (e.g. the va_arg family of macros in C varies between posix and windows)

Undefined behaviour means that *anything* (literally) could happen. i.e. totally unspecified. (e.g. the behaviour of `i = ++i`).